# Problem reading values from .plist downloaded from webserver

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

My .plist and code to read it is described in http://pastie.org/605082

```
NSLog(@"Test %@\n",[test valueForKey:@"FirstName"]);
```

returns NULL and resultsRetrieved is not NULL;

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh... stupid! FirstName is NULL anyway... it's all fine

Comment: if you've answered your own question, either mark it as answered or delete the question